# Web scenario parsing access_token failing

Tags: regex, zabbix

In my first step of a Zabbix Web Scenario I am getting a token, thats works fine, it returns:
`{"access_token":"eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJ6bGw1MlgwWnNFMW9IMG5qZ0NNcElGT2tyWmUtcld6c0N3b0haRDAwbkpFIn0.e1pbHlfbmFtZSI6IlRlc3QiLCJlbWFpbCI6InNpbmFuODZwb2xhdEBnU2YbpGxVt451ewwLfeCPpmmSI4Q","expires_in":1800,"refresh_expires_in":300,"refresh_token":"eyJhW9uX3N0YXRlIjoiYWQ4N2VkN2YtZWU1Ni00NTJlLWFkNTMtMTkzMzBhYTA3MjI1Iiwic2NvcGUiOiJlbWFpbCBwcmR_DFdVE8ss3V5NP_qDsh73qWRDis","token_type":"Bearer","not-before-policy":1557749105,"session_state":"ad87ed7f-ee56-452e-ad53-19330aa07225","scope":"email profile"}`

In the same step I am trying to set a variable ("access_token") with the token I received.

I have configured:
Variables:

- name: {access_token}
- value: `regex:"(?<=access_token\":").+?(?=")"`

But getting:
`Step "Login" [2 of 3] failed: error in step variables "{access_token}=regex:"(?<=access_token\":").+?(?=")"": cannot extract the value of "{access_token}" from response`

Is my regular expression wrong? Checking it via an online regex checker (example: https://regex101.com/r/HEVn9a/1) it seems the regular expression is fine.

Comment: Is `regex:"(?<=access_token\":").+?(?=")"` the whole value you enter, or just `(?<=access_token\":").+?(?=")` ? Your expression looks fine

Comment: Why don't you use a `JSON` parser on a `JSON` response instead of fiddling with regular expressions here?